# Else if with Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to make paragraph 1 show on a certain list of pages and paragraph 2 show on the pages not mentioned. The problem is, that I am seeing paragraph 2 on all pages.

This is not my code I was asked to make adjustments to already existing code and I am not very savvy with JS so please forgive my ignorance. Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks for reading.

Code:

```
if ((querystring('category') == '1')
    && (querystring('category') == '2')
    && (querystring('category') == '3')
    && (querystring('category') == '4')
    )
{
    var productContent = $('div#catalogContainer').html();
    var textContent = "<p>Paragraph 1</p>"
    $('div#catalogContainer').html(productContent + textContent);


}
else 
{
    var productContent = $('div#catalogContainer').html();
    var fullTextContent = "<p>Paragraph 2</p>"
$('div#catalogContainer').html(productContent + fullTextContent);
```

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What is your question actually? I don't see syntax issues here.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified. I am seeing paragraph 2 on all pages.

Comment: that depends on what `querystring('category')` returns. Please show the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the result of `querystring('category')` doesn't change each time it's called, you want to use `||` instead of `&&`.

Your `if` statment is basically asking if *all* of those things are true. If `querystring('category')` is simultaneously equal to `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, and `'4'`, then show paragraph 1, otherwise show paragraph 2. Which may explain why paragraph 2 is always shown, since one thing can't be equal to all four of those at the same time.

If you change to `||` instead, you're asking if `querystring('category')` is equal to *at least one* of those four things, instead of *all* four of them at the same time.